# Can SharePoint be used as out of the box BPM tool ?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, business-process-management, k2

Can SharePoint be used as out of the box BPM tool ? if it can, what are the limitation ?

I have come across 3rd party tools like K2 which does the job but want to know if sharepoint can do it on its own ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint is much more of a "Document Mangement" or "ECM" tool, in my opinion.  But in the interest of full disclosure I've worked for over 10 years with tools specifically designed to solve BPM problems.

IMO, if you are doing true BPM and not Case / Document management you need a tool that supports Business Process Modeling Notation (BPMN).  To my knowledge Sharepoint does not do that.

For relatively simple "processes" where some or all of the following are true, you can certainly use Sharepoint.  In effect I think you would be doing more Case management and not true BPM.

- You don't require a system to enforce the order of the activities.
- The participants are empowered to determine which steps are required / optional.
- The results of previous steps don't change what the next steps are, or, if they do, it really requires a human to decide those steps, not the system.
- There are few if any integrations to other IT systems.
- Tracking of process throughput isn't a top requirement.

Again, this is all from the perspective of a person that has used BPM focused tools for 10+ years, so my expectations of a BPM system maybe different from someone new to the space.